# how can i implement this search

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i'm trying to develop a search that allow me to accomplish this

**String to search**

```
This is a text
```

**the user input**

```
this_is_a_text
this a text
tihs a txt <----notes that the user made a wrong input
```

but always gave me the best coincidence that would by `this is a text`

I want to know if the possible to do with the use of `contains` and `freetext`. I'm also i been thinking to do it matching character by character in a method in c# loading all the records because there only 300 hundred  and makeing a percentage of equals. But this are just ideas can someone help me.

**UPDATE**

I tried with the function soundex but it doesn't help me to much...

Comment: do you really want to swap `input` for `text` in your search?

Comment: @Abe Miessler sorry my mistake i already modify the question

Comment: This is quite unclear as to how you are searching... does "String to search" just have to contain the "use input"? Also, to what records are you referring, and "percentage of equals"? Are you just trying to search entries in a SQL database? Please clarify.

Comment: @Greg Jackson Like i said before it was a mistake redacting my question and i already modified

Comment: Ok, it's now slightly clearer, but I still don't really understand the question. Does `this_is_a_text` match? If so, why? Are underscores a special case in your search? Does `this a text` match? And you still haven't clarified the architecture of your code. Is there a reason you can't use SQL's build-in text searching?

Comment: @Greg Jackson it's data that i can't manipulate it came in so many ways that just can find the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to do a one off reconciliation of data you are probably best loading both lists to match into C# and then use an [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm such as [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to iterate through best matches. Can be very time consuming but like I say - if you only have to do once...

You could implement this algorithm as a function in SQLServer (a Googling will find you plenty of people who have already done this for you...). Also, algorithms such as these can give unwanted or unexpected matches where a human matcher would have picked another alternative.

Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace method.

var stringToSearch = userInputText.Replace('_', ' ');

Comment: hi and thanks for asking notes that the user in put may change i modifed my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Soundex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx).

Comment: hi, and thanks for asking i tried, but for multiples words it's not the best tool